# how to change the font size?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a textarea field in jquery. When I enter anything in that 
text area and if I change the font family and font color and font
size it should  get changed.

In my below code when I write any thing in the 
text area and change the font family and font color its getting changed, 
but when i try to change the font size it's not getting changed.
I have font size as text area means whatever I give size it should get changed, but this issue I'm unable to solve.

Please can any one help me to solve this please.

```js
$("#ff").change(function() {
  $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
});

$("#size").change(function() {
  $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});

$("#color").change(function() {
  $('.changeMe').css("color", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-top:120px; padding-left:120px">

  <textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="changeMe" placeholder="Enter something"></textarea>

  <br><br>

  <form id="myform">

    <label>Select Font Family</label>
    <select id="ff">
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
      <option value="Verdana">Verdana </option>
      <option value="Times ">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <label>Select Font size</label>
    <input type="text" id="size"><br><br>

    <label>Select color</label>
    <select id="color">
      <option value="orange" style="background-color: orange;">orange</option>
      <option value="red" style="background-color: red;">red</option>
      <option value="pink" style="background-color: pink;">pink</option>
      <option value="blue" style="background-color: blue;">blue</option>
    </select><br><br>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it correctly applied

Comment: I changed the font size to 5 using your runnable snippet above and it works correctly (using the latest version of Chrome). Obviously for the "change" event to fire on the textbox, you have to move the focus away from the textbox (e.g. by tabbing or clicking to another control), so it's not an intuitive control system, but there's no obvious problem with the code. Have you experience an issue in some specific browser perhaps?

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me; the textarea's font size is updated accordingly.

Comment: sir when i enter manually say if i give size of 30px it's not taking please can u let me know what i should do

Comment: @keerthipatil just write `30`, not `30px` into the box - your code already adds the "px" automatically. I just tried it with `30` and the font size increases correctly, once you exit the textbox.

Comment: sir is it possible to do it in php also ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to use below code in order to achieve what you want.
This keyup function will change font size on every keypress event.

```
$("#size").on("keyup", function() {
$('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: If you use `keyup` you'll get several events while the user is typing in the text box - is that what's required here?

Comment: ya sir i got what actually i wanted, thank you for helping

Comment: sir is it possible to do it in php also ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of input you can use select option for fontsize

Like this...

```
<select id="size">
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
</select>
```

or else if you can use input field then you have to use another event like on click.

Comment: sir if i want to add the size manually what i should do ? i know using drop down sir but i want to add manually the size

Comment: sir can u edit my code and let me know because i tried what u said but im not getting the desired result

Comment: sir is it possible to do it in php also ?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it with `php` but the flow is that first your `input` from  your `form` goes to `server` and then you have to set those `input` for your corresponding `textarea` and then send back that updated code to `client` but it is not a good practice because it will create delay or `round trip` time `to-from` server. so avoid it. But even you want to try it you can do it and if you have done it then post some code i will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try this...

Just for reference purpose.

but effect of value change visible focus changes from `input box`

```
$("#size").on('change',function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

Comment: sir is it possible to do it in php also ?

Comment: @AmanKumar Have given a good explanation. you should to avoid it . but just want to learning purpose you can do it.